# Campaign Member Activity VS Object Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, campaign-member

I would like to double check what is the best practice that applies to the next use case:

> In a journey, I would like to check if a customer already exists as a
>   record in the Campaign Member object (Find and Update using the
>   Campaign Member Activity). If not, the record has to be created.

In case this record doesnt exist, I see the only option is using the Object Activity and 'Create new record'. See screenshot below. Is this the best way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Why would use an Object Activity to create a Campaign Member record that doesn't exist? You achieve the same thing using the Campaign Member Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Campaign Member Activity is limited to one basic usecase, simply injecting newly added members to a campaign into a journey. If that's all you need, go for it.

Anything more "sophisticated" including duplicate checks can be achieved with the Object activity. In other words, you can always do more with the Object activity, thus you can consider Campaign Member Activity as a shorthand path to one particular usecase.